# How to create a batch file to backup Mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, batch-file

I have been trying to create a batch file to backup MySQL database. All worked fine but the backup is just empty. I don't know where have gone wrong. Here is my code

```
set year=%DATE:~10,4%
set day=%DATE:~7,2%
set mnt=%DATE:~4,2%
set hr=%TIME:~0,2%
set min=%TIME:~3,2%

IF %day% LSS 10 SET day=0%day:~1,1%
IF %mnt% LSS 10 SET mnt=0%mnt:~1,1%
IF %hr% LSS 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%
IF %min% LSS 10 SET min=0%min:~1,1%

set backuptime=%year%-%day%-%mnt%-%hr%-%min%
echo %backuptime%
set dbuser=root
set dbpass=vsplabs
set mysqldumpexe="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe"
set backupfldr="C:\Users\sowmya\Desktop\Mysqlbackups"
set datafldr="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data"
set zipper="c:\MySQLBackups\zip\7za.exe"
pushd %datafldr%
echo "Pass each name to mysqldump.exe and output an individual .sql file for each"
@echo off
FOR /D %%F IN (*) DO (
IF NOT [%%F]==[performance_schema] (
SET %%F=!%%F:@002d=-!
%mysqldumpexe% --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --databases --routines --log-error=%errorLogPath% %%F > "%backupfldr%%%F.%backuptime%.sql"
) ELSE (
echo Skipping DB backup for performance_schema
)
)
 echo "Zipping all files ending in .sql in the folder"
 %zipper% a -tzip "%backupfldr%FullBackup.%backuptime%.zip" "%backupfldr%*.sql
 echo "done"
 popd
```

And another issue I just wanted only one database its being retrieving all the databases from database..How to modify that and And i have been getting an extra database named as "mysql"

Comment: The mysql db is a standard db which stores previliges and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This can be run directly in cmd (I wrapped the line but it should not be wrapped):
You should give the root access.

```
mysql.exe -uroot -p1234 -s -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" |
for /F "usebackq" %D in (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"`)
do mysqldump %D -uroot -p1234 > S:\Backup\MySQL\%D.sql
```

In a batch file you will need to escape % with an additional %, that is use %%D.

Comment: The application user cant do all this so I have been creating batch file so that he can simply run that and the database will be stored in a specific folder

Comment: You can definitely add my piece of code to a batch with escapes.

Comment: Then how about the path and db name along with date